# How to return the tab/worksheet name when combining worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with an Excel file that has states separated, with data, as their own tabs/worksheets (so 50 tabs).

I ran the following macro to combine all tabs, which worked.  However, it doesn't include the name of the tab (each state).

I need such data split up by state (i.e. tab name).

```vb
Sub Combine()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(J).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Next
End Sub
```

I need the combined file to be separated by state (tab name) but also include the columns of each.

Comment: A hint: `Sheets(J).Name` would give you the sheet name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub Combine()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsComb As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsComb = wb.Worksheets.Add(before:=wb.Worksheets(1))
    wsComb.Name = "Combined"
    wb.Worksheets(2).Rows(1).Copy wsComb.Range("A1") 'copy header
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets            'loop all worksheets
        If ws.Name <> wsComb.Name Then      'exclude "Combined" sheet
            Set rng = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            With wsComb.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2)
                .Resize(rng.Rows.Count).Value = ws.Name 'fill tab name in ColA
                rng.Copy .Offset(0, 1)                  'paste data to Col B
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, after looking closer, it appears it only combined half the tabs (through Missouri).

Any ideas what may have caused this?

Comment: `For Each ws In wb.Worksheets` should check every worksheet in the workbook.  If there's no error and it just excludes some of the sheets then I have no idea why that would happen...

Comment: Tim, I found an error in this line: Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)

After I removed that line, it ran all the worksheets!

Thanks again!

Comment: Didn't you want to exclude the headers from the combined data?

Comment: Ideally yes, but it errored out for some reason and when I removed that and ran it again without that line, it combined all 50 tabs.  With the line in, it would stop halfway through.

Comment: OK, I found the error..it stopped because a header was different.  I fixed that and it works 100% now!